# When requesting via python using firebase-admin in firestore, the program freezes

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I created a regular project on firebase, connected firestore there, generated a private key, wrote a simple code for adding an element to the collection, but the program freezes on the line of the request. Moreover, the strange thing is that before that I made a telegram bot that applied to firestore on the same principles, hosted it, and it now works fine.

code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
import time

cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

db.collection('persons').add({
    'name': 'vlad',
    'age': 40
})

print('done')
```

At first I thought that it might not be possible to use two projects on the free version of firebase at the same time, but after I stopped the bot that I hosted, nothing changed. Then I tried to create a new Google account through which I entered firebase, there I also created a project with firestore, but nothing changed again.

Another interesting thing is that if I run the code of this bot, which I have hosted, on my computer, then access to firestore does not work there either, BUT THE SAME CODE WORKS ON A REMOTE SERVER. I also need to note that my javascript site with svelte works fine with firestore.

this is part of firebase from my bot:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from typing import Union

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

user_dict_template = {
    'state': None,
    'lang': 'en'
}

cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
users_db = db.collection('users_tg')


def get_users() -> list[int]:
    users = list(map(lambda x: int(x.id), users_db.stream()))
    return users


def add_user(uid: Union[int, str]) -> None:
    users_db.document(str(uid)).set(deepcopy(user_dict_template))


def get_user(uid: Union[int, str]) -> dict:
    user = users_db.document(str(uid)).get()
    return user.to_dict()


def is_user_updated(uid: Union[int, str]) -> bool:
    return set(get_user(uid).keys()) == set(user_dict_template.keys())


def update_user(uid: Union[int, str]) -> None:
    old_user = get_user(uid)
    new_user = deepcopy(user_dict_template)

    for key in old_user.keys():
        if new_user.get(key):
            new_user[key] = old_user[key]

    users_db.document(str(uid)).update(new_user)


def update_value(uid: Union[int, str], update: dict) -> None:
    user = users_db.document(str(uid))
    user.update(update)
```

Realtime database works